# SMTP - adding headers

Tags: .net, vb.net, email, smtp, smtpclient

I am trying to create an application in which I can reply to emails. I am using the smtp library to send the emails. What I am trying to achieve is creating an email tread. I am trying to do this by setting the "Reference" header before sending the email.
I am trying the following:

```
mailMsg.Headers.Add("References", Header)
```

The value of variable header is: `<CAAPa+tw4HWCFbCO89FmTP+U4gbfD46wsbjzy=_sLK9hu=KuoRA@mail.gmail.com>`

But I am getting the following error:
An invalid character was found in header name. and it does not specify which character. 
Any help would be greatly appreciated since very little material on this matter is available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After further testing and tweaking the correct format should be:

```
 mailMsg.Headers.Add("In-Reply-To", Header)
```